# Make 2 square holes in a cube

Tags: modeling

Good morning, 
I'm trying to make two square holes in a cube.
I managed to make the first one:
[image]

But when it's time to do the second one, the software can't take the sides of the cube anymore since the cube has been transformed, I can't select the top side but only certain side of the lines, so if I try it gives me something like that:

[image]

May I know how to make two holes? Thanks.

Comment: You should use ```Boolean modifier```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What steps exactly are you taking for this process? Could I suggest using The Boolean modifier? If you don't want to use that you could always use the knife tool or CTRL+R to create edge loops.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use Knife Project with the **Cut through** enabled. It gives you two faces on the opposite sides. You remove the faces and use Bridge edge loops.